# Return second from the last oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT * FROM
          (
           SELECT DISTINCT(TRUNC(receipt_dstamp)) 
           FROM inventory
           WHERE substr(location_id,1,3) = 'GI-'
           ORDER BY 1 ASC 
          )
           WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
```

Output: [image]

Hi all, i've got this subeqery and in this case my oldest date is in row 1, i want to retrive only second from the last(from the top in this case) which is gonna be 01-SEP-21.
I was trying to play with ROWNUM and OVER but without any results, im getting blank output.

Thank you.

Full query:

```
SELECT TRUNC(receipt_dstamp) as old_putaway_date, COUNT(tag_id) as tag_old_putaway
    FROM inventory
WHERE substr(location_id,1,3) = 'GI-' 
AND TRUNC(receipt_dstamp) IN (  
                                SELECT * FROM
                                (
                                    SELECT DISTINCT(TRUNC(receipt_dstamp)) 
                                    FROM inventory
                                    WHERE substr(location_id,1,3) = 'GI-'
                                    ORDER BY 1 ASC 
                                )
                                WHERE ROWNUM = 1
                              )
GROUP BY TRUNC(receipt_dstamp);
```

Comment: What is the logic of your expected output? Your query have no `ORDER BY` clause, so that `second from the last` has no meaning here (by theory, it should change as you run your query again)

Comment: its not possible to have 2 column as output. query  has only one  : DISTINCT(TRUNC(receipt_dstamp))

Comment: Yes guys, correct, i've updated the question by my full query. So by running this query im getting the latest date and count(tag). I need to get results just for the second from the last, which in this case is 10-AUG-2021.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simplify the entire query to:

```sql
SELECT old_putaway_date,
       COUNT(tag_id) as tag_old_putaway
FROM   (
  SELECT TRUNC(receipt_dstamp) as old_putaway_date,
         tag_id,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TRUNC(receipt_dstamp)) AS rnk
  FROM   inventory
  WHERE substr(location_id,1,3) = 'GI-'
)
WHERE rnk = 3
GROUP BY
       old_putaway_date;
```

Comment: Yes, for the whole query that is the best approach in my opinion. I wrote my answer when the request showed the subquery only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dense_rank() :

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT L.*,DENSE_RANK() 
OVER (PARTITION BY L.TAG_OLD_PUTAWAY ORDER BY L.OLD_PUTAWAY_DATE DESC) RNK 
FROM 
(
SELECT TRUNC(receipt_dstamp) as old_putaway_date, COUNT(tag_id) as tag_old_putaway
    FROM inventory
WHERE substr(location_id,1,3) = 'GI-' 
AND TRUNC(receipt_dstamp) IN (  
                                SELECT * FROM
                                (
                                    SELECT DISTINCT(TRUNC(receipt_dstamp)) 
                                    FROM inventory
                                    WHERE substr(location_id,1,3) = 'GI-'
                                    ORDER BY 1 ASC 
                                )
                                WHERE ROWNUM = 1
                              )
GROUP BY TRUNC(receipt_dstamp)
) L
) WHERE RNK = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old Oracle syntax that is not standard compliant in the regard that it relies on a subquery result order. (Sub)query results are unordered data sets by definition, but Oracle lets this pass in order to make their `ROWNUM` work with it.

Oracle now supports the standard SQL `FETCH` clause, which you should use instead.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(receipt_dstamp) AS receipt_date
FROM inventory
WHERE SUBSTR(location_id, 1, 3) = 'GI-'
ORDER BY receipt_date
OFFSET 2 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6

Comment: You want `OFFSET 2 ROW` rather than `OFFSET 1 ROW` as the OP wants the 2nd from last (i.e. 3rd least value).

Comment: @MT0: Thank you. Yes, "second from last" was a bit misleading. They really just want the third oldest row.